# What is the value of the letters?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What is the value of the letters **A** and **B** in the figure down below? The square and the circle are independent from one another, i.e. they are solved independently.

Here follows **my train of thought**:

For the square I first noticed that the middle row sums to 30 and that the main diagonal also sums to 30. Then I began filling in the empty squares such that each row, column and diagonal sums to 30, but doing this I end up with that **A** can be any value between 0 and 12.

For the circle I noticed that the sum of each piece is 1 greater or smaller than the piece straight opposite to it. This left me with **B** being either 6 or 8.

I think that when you have found the right solution it should be no uncertainty to what the correct value is. This is why I think that my solution is wrong.

[image]

Edit: The puzzle is from [here](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC5H0VP_realmyst-6-matematisk-problematik?guid=aaaebe86-66f3-4113-970e-44f407059cad). It's a geocache myst. In this myst you solve several logic puzzels that in the end give you the coordinates to where the cache is hidden. I have solved all the logic puzzels except the two that I have posted here.

Comment: To make all lines 30 with no number repeated on the same line, A can only be 1 or 11

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that as well, but you still have the ambiguity of A being either 1 or 11 and not a definite single-value, which feels weird to me since logic puzzels .

Do you have any take on the circle @JoshuaBizley?

Comment: Not yet... could it be intended that there are multiple coordinates people have to check?

Comment: Is this from an ongoing geocache, or are we to believe the 'found it's?

Comment: I don't know about Myst geocaches (is this a geocache inside the game?!) but real-world geocaches can be found any number of times by any number of people and there's no prize beyond the satisfaction of recording that you found the cache.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to the GeoCache? Because I get O=sqrt(42) using my answer, which can't be right.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes it's an ongoing cach and I get O=sqrt(42) here as well. I don't know the right answer but it's possible to verify it [here](http://geocheck.org/geo_inputchkcoord.php?gid=6197248a088b9e4-01db-4cfa-aa87-51db142bc6a5&e=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1:

> Using sum of lines=30 and distinct entries on a line, A=1 or 11. But using the equations given at the bottom of the page, A is a single digit, so A=1. However, from the definition of Q (L=1), AB+1 is a divisor of 100 greater than 10, so A=3 (B=8) or 4 (B=6).

For 2:

> B is 6. If it was 8, swapping the contents of the 32 cell (make 2 inside, 3 outside), and also the 53 cell, makes the inner circle 1234567, and so if the answer was 8 then the setter would have done just that, and put the 8 on the inside! But they didn't, so the answer is 6.

A more logical explanation:

> Alternate segments go +1, (+2,-1), +1, (+2,-1) with their opposite segment.

To say 'Found It!':

> E=3, FG=21, CD=24, H=4, IK=10, L=4. From M, A=3, B=8. So now you know!